# Wagtail: How to use preview on editors page without Django templates?

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-admin, wagtail-apiv2

I started to use Wagtail with the v2 rest endpoint and do not understand how to implement the preview.

I use Nuxt as a frontend and can not find how to integrate previewing on the page editor in Wagtail admin. Is this not possible/supported at the moment?